# XMLHttpRequest With Canvas on Loading Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, canvas

I'm trying to load a page with a canvas via XHR and the canvas is not displaying. I believe the issue is due to the fact that I'm not appending it to the XHR response.

**Main Page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function LoadContent1()
{
var LoadContent1;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    LoadContent1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

LoadContent1.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (LoadContent1.readyState == 4 && LoadContent1.status == 200)
    {           
        document.getElementById("loadContent1").innerHTML = LoadContent1.responseText;
        document.getElementById("loadingImageContent1").src = "1-pixel.gif";
        $("#loadContent1Parent").hide();
        $("#loadContent1Child").hide();
    }
}

LoadContent1.open("GET", "page.php", true);
LoadContent1.send();
}

</script>
```

**Page Loaded Via XHR (Page.php)**

```
<canvas id="mycanvas_pie" height="290" width="290"></canvas>
<canvas id="mycanvas_pie2" height="290" width="290"></canvas>

<script>
    var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("mycanvas_pie").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData1,opts);
    var myPie2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("mycanvas_pie2").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData3,opts);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to make sure that your AJAX call is running, and it returns with the correct HTML code.
You can easily find out this in any modern browser by using breakpoints for example, or by using the console.log() method.

You also need to make sure that the element - which you are trying to fill with the response - is already exists in the DOM. In your case it's ID is "loadContent1".

Other Recommendations:

- I don't recommend you to use (almost) the same name in variable/function/object names, and for DOM elements. Try to use descriptive names because your code can be easily confusing, even in this tiny snippet
- if it's not a must, try to avoid running javascript codes automatically when receiving and displaying an HTML code, because of security reasons. You can put that javascript code into your callback function for example, or more better if you organize those lines into a separate object.

Comment: Yes, it returns with the correct HTML code, it just displays everything but the canvas. Any thoughts on why this is? Thanks for your recommendations, I'll take them into consideration.

Comment: Do you mean that the canvas elements are inserted correctly into the DOM, but the Chart is not displaying on it? In that case i would suppose that the Chart library is not well started/configured. I would try to draw something on the canvas by myself to be sure that the element is really ready. If that is OK then the problem is definitely within the Chart or it's config. You should also check that the canvas elements are not hidden by CSS rules.